# Wineserver hang everytime I try to install anything in wine

Tags: 18.04, wine

Everytime I try to install anything in wine, I always get the error

> "Running /usr/bin/wineserver -w. This will hang until all wine
>   processes in prefix=/home/username/.wine terminate"

I'm able to kill the process but installations always fail. Are there any fixes to this error, or anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. It means that wine started your program and will resume at the end.
The program you are trying to install may not be supported by wine.

I suggest you take a look at https://appdb.winehq.org/ and search your app. You will find there what dependencies you need and workarounds (if needed) to install. If you still cannot run it using the lastest wine version you should have a look at the wine forums : https://forum.winehq.org/